# How can I show a subfolder from another SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, site-collection, modern-experience, folder

I want to display subfolders from site B on site A.

I have tried the 'embed web part', but I can only embed the root folder('documents library') because I can't find a complete URL for subfolders.

How can I show the specific subfolder in my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed any subfolder from document library using embed web part. You just need to get the correct URL of your subfolder like below:

1. Go to subfolder you want to embed
2. Click on **Open the details pane** (`i` icon) from command bar (top right side)
3. **Copy direct link** using the copy icon highlighted in below image

[image]

Generally, URL of subfolder is like:

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<siteName>/<libraryName>/folder/subfolder
```

Then you can embed it using `iframe` code like below:

```
<iframe src="https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/Shared%20Documents/folder1/folder2" title="Folder from site B" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Add content to your page using the Embed web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8)

Comment: Many thanks for your help! This method looks good!

Answer (score 0):

Step1:
Copy the direct path of the subfolder in details panel:

[image]

Step2:Add a Highlighted content web part in site A, choose Custom query, and fill in the path with direct link of the subfolder:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, this method cannot correctly display the subfolders(Test1/ Test2) in this subfolder(Test 1)