# Error on Adding an HTML onto SharePoint Site Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, html, embedded

I'm trying to add an HTML into my SharePoint Site Page (Teams Site) and am following the instructions at this [link here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-embed-html-code-into-sharepoint/9409b31f-00ce-4b55-abb1-03897403bb37#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20the,on%20the%20modern%20SharePoint%20pages.) from Microsoft which guides on how to do so.

Steps:

- So I've renamed my HTML to an ASPX.
- I've uploaded it into the document library at the following page: "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
- But when I try to view it, by following: https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/Shared%20Documents/myfile.aspx it shows up with the following error. Would appreciate any help on this.

[image]

> Sorry, something went wrong. File not found.

More specifics: I'm using modern version of sharepoint without admin rights. I am basically trying to add an html file that users can view instantly (not the code but the output), and hosted on this SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using correct URL of your `.aspx` file. To copy the correct URL/path of file follow my answer given at: [How can I show a subfolder from anohter SharePoint site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/296790/how-can-i-show-a-subfolder-from-anohter-sharepoint-site/296793#296793)

I followed below steps & it is working fine for me:

1. Created a HTML file on computer & then renamed it with `.aspx` extension.
2. Upload `.aspx` file to Site Assets library on SharePoint site.
3. Copied direct link to `.aspx` file using above mentioned method
4. Create a modern site page and added "Embed" web part.
5. Added `.aspx` file URL in "Website address or embed code" section of Embed web part settings.
6. Published the page.

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Hi this did not work, it only returned the same error. Your steps 4-6 are no problem, but step 3 does not appear to work for me. I'm trying a URL which is nearly identical: https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<siteName>/SiteAssets/filename.aspx but this still returns the same error? In addition, clicking the (i) info button does not provide me the path. In case it'll help, my URL for the SiteAssets folder which you've recommended me to upload into is https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<siteName>/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: Try embedding using `<iframe>` element as mentioned in my answer at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/296790/how-can-i-show-a-subfolder-from-anohter-sharepoint-site/296793#296793

Comment: Thanks - yes I've tried that too but the issue is that the page itself doesn't even load either.