# Add a word document to the SP site left pane

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, document, quick-launch

I have a SP site which has a list and, I would like to add a clickable `Read me` document to the left pane under Recycle bin.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint default "Documents" (or any other) document library
2. Upload a document in the document library whose link will be added in navigation
3. Get the "direct link" to document using method explained at: [How can I show a subfolder from another SharePoint site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/296790/how-can-i-show-a-subfolder-from-another-sharepoint-site/296793#296793)
4. Click on **Edit** link in left navigation (below "Shared with us" in image attached to your question)
5. Hover on navigation below Recycle bin link and select **+**
6. On the Add a link dialog box, Select Link and use direct link to document similar to this:

   [image]
7. Select **OK**

**Microsoft documentation**: [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)