# Cannot pull image (url) with JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a lookup (choice) column - Work Location - I would like another column - logo - to pull from an image library depending on what choice was given in Work Location.

After some research, I came up with the following:

```
{  
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",  
  "elmType": "img",  
  "style": {  
    "width": "100px"  
  },  
  "attributes": {  
   "src": "=if([Work_x0020_Location] == ‘Main Office', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EVrDuspyW7VHrbdro8qIyfUB-zJmvTfRs6mt4UCHS8oMgQ?e=JxjhDx', if([Work_x0020_Location]  == ‘Remote/Home', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EWzUpzmEPrZOm5QlGcmImfEB8x7bl7GEBEhWGuh-r1eTrQ?e=dhrUOM', if([Work_x0020_Location] == ‘DOD Installation', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EZmme3yMtitAh52a-RG8TbABJZ4TpmlIstVVKz7WoaurZQ?e=mhxtbX',if([Work_x0020_Location] == ‘VA Facility’,’https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EWTh90hhj51NjOOMZf2PO1sBADYszr_YqivKfMcB_WwULw?e=gZNC2j','https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/echodu/SiteAssets/icon/na.jpg', if([Work_x0020_Location] == ‘Indian Health Service', ‘https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EcczRDIKTsdMqLhCD4LPErYByTy9e-P-ZH1oigwzGrjPAg?e=0hBOYA', if([Work_x0020_Location] == ‘US Government', ‘https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EWTh90hhj51NjOOMZf2PO1sBADYszr_YqivKfMcB_WwULw?e=gZNC2j',)))))"  
  }  
}
```

I also tried:

```
{  
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",  
  "elmType": "img",  
  "style": {  
    "width": "100px"  
  },  
  "attributes": {  
   "src": "=if(@Work_x0020_Location.lookupValue == ‘Main Office', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EVrDuspyW7VHrbdro8qIyfUB-zJmvTfRs6mt4UCHS8oMgQ?e=JxjhDx', if(@Work_x0020_Location.lookupValue  == ‘Remote/Home', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EWzUpzmEPrZOm5QlGcmImfEB8x7bl7GEBEhWGuh-r1eTrQ?e=dhrUOM', if(@Work_x0020_Location.lookupValue == ‘DOD Installation', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EZmme3yMtitAh52a-RG8TbABJZ4TpmlIstVVKz7WoaurZQ?e=mhxtbX',if(@Work_x0020_Location.lookupValue == ‘VA Facility’,’https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EWTh90hhj51NjOOMZf2PO1sBADYszr_YqivKfMcB_WwULw?e=gZNC2j','https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/echodu/SiteAssets/icon/na.jpg', if(@Work_x0020_Location.lookupValue == ‘Indian Health Service', ‘https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EcczRDIKTsdMqLhCD4LPErYByTy9e-P-ZH1oigwzGrjPAg?e=0hBOYA', if(@Work_x0020_Location.lookupValue == ‘US Government', ‘https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EWTh90hhj51NjOOMZf2PO1sBADYszr_YqivKfMcB_WwULw?e=gZNC2j',)))))"  
  }  
}
```

I ran both through JSON checker and found no syntax errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you try suggestions in my answer below? Is it working for you now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to use the correct internal name of column in this format: `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`. So, use: `[$Work_x0020_Location]` at all places
2. Make sure you are using correct image URL in this format: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/libraryName/folderName/na.jpg'`. Follow steps given here to find the URL in above format: [How can I show a subfolder from another SharePoint site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/296790/how-can-i-show-a-subfolder-from-another-sharepoint-site/296793#296793)

Use JSON like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "width": "100px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "=if([$Work_x0020_Location] == 'Main Office', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EVrDuspyW7VHrbdro8qIyfUB-zJmvTfRs6mt4UCHS8oMgQ?e=JxjhDx', if([$Work_x0020_Location]  == 'Remote/Home', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EWzUpzmEPrZOm5QlGcmImfEB8x7bl7GEBEhWGuh-r1eTrQ?e=dhrUOM', if([$Work_x0020_Location] == 'DOD Installation', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EZmme3yMtitAh52a-RG8TbABJZ4TpmlIstVVKz7WoaurZQ?e=mhxtbX', if([$Work_x0020_Location] == 'VA Facility', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EWTh90hhj51NjOOMZf2PO1sBADYszr_YqivKfMcB_WwULw?e=gZNC2j', if([$Work_x0020_Location] == 'Indian Health Service', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EcczRDIKTsdMqLhCD4LPErYByTy9e-P-ZH1oigwzGrjPAg?e=0hBOYA', if([$Work_x0020_Location] == 'US Government', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/:i:/s/HR/EWTh90hhj51NjOOMZf2PO1sBADYszr_YqivKfMcB_WwULw?e=gZNC2j', 'https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/echodu/SiteAssets/icon/na.jpg'))))))"
  }
}
```

**Documentations**:

1. [SharePoint Column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: I used the JSON you posted - but changed all the URLs to the format you suggested. When I leave your code in tact, it fills [$logo] with the broken image icon in the final line of your JSON, no matter which choice is selected. When I remove the na.jpg line, it leaves [$logo] empty. I cannot get it to pull the correct image (or any image other than na.jpg) based on the choice made in [$Work_x0020_Location]

Comment: Make sure you have shown/included work location column in list view. This is required to use the column in json formatting.

Comment: Yes, Work Location is included in the list view.

Comment: Got it. Changed to pulling based on WorkLocationID # instead of text.
Working code: ..."src": "=if([$Work_x0020_Location_x003a_ID] == '1', 'https://argenttechnet.sharepoint.com/sites/Hr/Images1/WLT/AT_icon.png',...

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!